# Take photo of certain size with Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I need to take photo using **system camera application**. My simplified code looks like this:

```
@Composable
fun takePhoto(){     
val cameraLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(),
    onResult = { success ->  ... }
)
...
if (hasCamPermission) {
    val uri = ComposeFileProvider.getImageUri(context)
    imageUri = uri
    cameraLauncher.launch(uri)
}
```

But I want to compress resulted photo. Is there any way to request photo of certain size or I need to do it manually?             What is the best way to do it?

Comment: "Is there any way to request photo of certain size" -- no. Using `TakePicture`, the user does not need to take a photo, and you do not get a vote in any characteristics of that photo, such as resolution. If you want to use `TakePicture`, you will need to revise the photo yourself. Or, use CameraX or other camera libraries and have your app take the photo directly, and you should have options for controlling the resolution.